# Find the number of possible ways to fill the entries of the grid.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, divisibility

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Consider an $m\times m$ grid with a 1 in the upper left corner and an n in the lower right corner that satisfies the following property. Let the entry in the ith row and jth column be $a_{ij}$. Suppose the grid satisfies that for any entry $a_{ij}$, any entry directly to the right of it is divisible by $a_{ij}$ and any entry directly below it is divisible by $a_{ij}$. Find the number of possible ways to fill the entries of the grid.

Now it easily follows from the problem's condition that if $a_{ij}$ is the entry at row i and column j, then every entry $a_{kl}$ with $i\leq k, l\leq j$ satisfies that $a_{ij} | a_{kl}.$ Let $D_{m,n}$ denote the desired entry of ways for an $m\times m$ grid satisfying the problem's conditions. Thus every entry in the grid is a divisor of $n$. For a positive integer e and prime p, let $v_p(e)$ denote the highest exponent b of p such that $p^b $ divides e. Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$ be the prime factorization of $n,$ where each $e_i\ge 1$. Note that we may choose the highest exponents of a prime factor of n that divides each entry in the grid independently, so we have that $D_{m,n} = \prod_{i=1}^k D_{m,p_i^{e_i}}.$ Hence it suffices to consider the case when $n$ is a prime power, say $n=p^k, k\ge 0$. If $n=1$ there is clearly only one way, so suppose otherwise. For $0\leq j\leq k$, let $b_{i,j}$ denote the number of entries e in the $i$th column such that $v_p(e) = j$. Note that for fixed j, $b_{i,j}$ is a nondecreasing sequence of size m.

> Fact 1: The number of nondecreasing sequences of size k consisting of elements from a set of integers of size n is precisely ${n+k-1\choose k}.$

Note that we cannot have $(b_{1,j}, b_{2,j},\cdots, b_{m,j}) = (0,0,\cdots, 0)$ or $(k,k,\cdots, k)$ for any $j > 0$, since the last column will always have $n,$ which is divisible by $p^j$ for any $0<j\leq k$ and the first column will always have 1, which is not divisible by $p^j$. The case where $k=1$ is straightforward; we just have by fact 1 and the above observation that the answer is ${2m\choose m}-2$ (indeed once we have the sequence $(b_{1,1},\cdots, b_{m,1})$ we must place p's in the last $b_{i,1}$ spots of the ith column and 1's elsewhere, so each way to fill the grid's entries uniquely corresponds to a sequence of $b_{i,1}$'s). So assume $k>1$.

It may help to exploit symmetry somehow. If $m$ is odd for instance, then it may be useful to consider $v_p(c)$, where c is the entry in the center of the grid. Now the entries in the first row and first column are in increasing order of $v_p(e)$. It's easy to count the number of possibilities for the first row, but the issue is that the entries in the second row depend on those in the first.

> Question: how can I complete the argument above to deal with the case where $k>1$?

Comment: Side note: It can be a bit confusing to read your writeup, because the notation $k$ is used numerous times in different settings. EG When you say "the case where $k=1$ is straightforward, is $k$ the 1) exponent of $n = p^k$, 2) The number of entries $k=m$. $\quad$ Another example is if $n$ refers to the prime power $ n = p^k$, or if $n$ is the number of terms. In particular, what does "since the last column will always have $n$" mean?

Comment: @user33096 If $n=p^3$, the number of possible ways  is
$\frac{(2m)!}{(m!)^2}(\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+1)!)^2}-1)$